# Passing sub class type in method parameters to super class type

Tags: java, inheritance

if i have this:

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
}
```

then can I pass an instance of C to a method asking for an instance of A? like this:

```
void aMethod(A anInstanceOfA){
// some code
}

C anInstanceOfC = new C();
aMethod(anInstanceOfC);
```

and if not, is there a way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, you can use an instance of C at any time you need an instance of A. That includes passing it to a method which requires an A parameter.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it? If you don't have Java installed on your machine you can use online compilers like https://ideone.com/

Comment: you can pass any subtype of `A` to `aMethod()`, btw you could've easily tested this online or in some ide

Comment: I was already confused before I even finished reading the title...Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I pass an instance of C to a method asking for an instance of A?

Yes, you can.  You can also assign an object whose class is `C` to a variable declared to be of type `A`.  Indeed, an instance of `C` *is* an instance of `A` (but not all instances of `A` are instances of `C`).